# I dont't understand why im getting syntax error on my code below. Can anyone help me?

Tags: mysql, cursor, declare

```
 DELIMITER ##
 create trigger tra_Price after update on assets_cdn_charge for each row
 begin
 declare res int;
 declare ids int;
 declare idq int;
 declare idt int;
 set res = (select price from assets_cdn_charge where price = new.price);
 set ids = (select id from assets_cdn_charge where price = new.price);
 DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM assets_cdn_composite WHERE cdn_charge_id = ids;
 open cur;
 ins_loop:LOOP
 fetch cur into idq;
 declare curs cursor for select id from assets_cdn_traffic where domain_name_id = idq;
 open curs;
 ins1_loop:LOOP
 fetch curs into idt;
 update assets_cdn_traffic set cost = traffic * res where domain_namd_id = idt;
 end LOOP;
 close curs;
 end LOOP;
 close cur;
 END; ##
```

when I run this code,I had get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM
>   assets_cdn_composite WHERE cdn_charge_id =' at line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because:

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement
>   **and must be at its start, before any other statements**.

...so that line should likely be moved before the two set statements above that point.

I believe that you're going to have other trouble if that fixes that error, because I don't know what you expect that query to retrieve as `idq` is declared before that point, but is not set to any value?

=====

UPDATE:

Below is an example from a previous comment about the possibility to eliminate cursors altogether. Try this:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE assets_cdn_traffic
        JOIN assets_cdn_composite ON assets_cdn_traffic.domain_name_id = assets_cdn_composite.cdn_charge_id
        JOIN assets_cdn_charge ON assets_cdn_charge.id = assets_cdn_composite.cdn_charge_id
    SET cost = traffic * NEW.price
    WHERE assets_cdn_charge.id = NEW.id
END
```

However, I would **try the update query separately before using in the trigger** to make sure that it works as expected. Replace the `NEW.price` and the `NEW.id` with test values to verify the handling.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I made a mistake,the idq must be ids at "declare curs cursor for select id from assets_cdn_traffic where domain_name_id = idq;"

Comment: Ok, but you will still have trouble with that line. All `DECLARE` statements **must appear at the start**, according to the documentation. Also, you have another typo here: `domain_namd_id`

Comment: thanks for yor help,I have understood，May be I can use left join.

Comment: Left join to what? ... Anyway, I'm thinking that you can simplify the queries, at least to have one less, and/or possibly even avoid the need for cursors completely, but it will take some effort.

Comment: becase I have three tables and they are relation,so I must be use left join.like this:DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT assets_cdn_traffic.id FROM assets_cdn_traffic left join assets_cdn_composite on assets_cdn_traffic.domain_namd_id= 
  assets_cdn_composite.id left join(select * from assets_cdn_charge where price = new.price) on assets_cdn_composite.cdn_charge_id=assets_cdn_charge.id;

Comment: DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id from assets_cdn_traffic where domain_name_id=(select id from \
 assets_cdn_composite where cdn_charge_id = (select id from assets_cdn_charge where price=new.price));                                               I do it like this ,but also not,  becase the first query is Multiple records,and the  second query also be Multiple records,then I don't how I can do

Comment: I updated my answer (at the bottom) for a potential query to replace all the cursors. As I mention below the code example, I would test the `UPDATE` query separately before adding to the trigger to verify handling.